# Custom navigation bar changes in one viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am working with a custom navigation bar. 
In my `AppDelegate` I've done this.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                     UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                                 UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Carrois Gothic" size:18.0f]
 }];
```

On `viewController` level I put buttons inside the `navigationController`. In all `viewControllers` I have only one button inside the `navigationbar`.

But in one VC I need to set 2 buttons and I also change the `backgroundImage` of the `navigationbar`. So what I copied the same code as above in the `ViewDidLoad` but now with other image. This is working.

But now I want in all other VC's the first `navigationbar`. So in my `viewDidDisappear` I copied again the code with the other image again.

The following is going wrong:

- The background image is not changing
- The leftbarbutton is not going away

Can anybody help me with this ?

**PS:** I am working with a `tabbarcontroller`. So if I say switching VC's I mean going to another tab in the tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not use the appearance proxy in the ViewController. Just set the background directly:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                         UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                  UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                 UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                             UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Carrois Gothic" size:18.0f]
}];
```

Comment: I am getting an error "unexpected @ in program". Could U please help me.

Comment: @chandru Did you use `@{` or just `@`?

Comment: That's what I am asking, I just copied the above code and pasted it